# Why pass a compile-time-static string as a parameter to a string-formatting function instead of including it in the format string?

Tags: c, format-string

In analyzing the C output of Ghidra's automatic decompiler, I spotted the following `sprintf` call:

```
some_function(char *shm_name, int key, int subkey) {
    ...
    sprintf(shm_name,"%s%d_%d","/XSAL_Shm_",key,subkey);
    ...
}
```

---

If I were writing this code myself, I would write

```
sprintf(shm_name,"/XSAL_Shm_%d_%d",key,subkey);
```

because I think it is clearer, easier to read & understand, and - in my experience - more common.

The code I was analyzing was written to run on QNX.

What reason might there be to write it as the former? Do any C style guides mandate/recommend either way? Is either more efficient?

Comment: Does `readelf -wm executablefile` show any macros? Maybe the original code had something like  `#define SHMPREFIX "/XSAL_Shm_"`

Comment: @MarkPlotnick `readelf -wm ...` produces no output. Nevertheless, that's a good reason I hadn't considered. Something similar shows up again later in the same function with an environment variable name, which I definitely imagine would be defined in a macro. This is probably the answer.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is basically a "style" question, meaning that any answers (including mine) are likely to be opinionated.  There's no "right" or "wrong" answer here.  (Such questions are generally discouraged on Stack Overflow, and by rights I should be voting to close this question rather than answering it.  But style issues can be interesting, so here goes.)

I've written code like that, occasionally, if the constant string is "a lot like" the variable strings, or if I imagine that the reader might imagine that the constant part could vary -- or if I imagine that one day the constant part might actually vary.

But I don't really like the way the code you posted is written.  If I were writing it, and if I thought the "constant" part belonged with the rest of the arguments, I'd write it as

```
sprintf(shm_name, "%s_%d_%d", "/XSAL_Shm", key, subkey);
```

or perhaps

```
sprintf(shm_name, "/%s_%d_%d", "XSAL_Shm", key, subkey);
```

Either of these forms makes it much easier to see the structure of the punctuation in one place, and the three different name components in the other place.

You talked about something being "clearer, easier to read & understand", and obviously this can be a matter of opinion and personal preference.  I agree that putting a constant string in with the "variables" is at least surprising.  Once the reader gets over the surprise, however, I think it *can* be easier to read and understand.  (But I certainly won't assert that *every* reader *will* find it easier to understand, or that you're wrong if you still disagree.)

While we're discussing this code, though, the other suggestion I'd make would be to replace `sprintf` with `snprintf`.  Assuming `shm_name` is a fixed-size array, I'd probably use

```
snprintf(shm_name, sizeof(shm_name) "/%s_%d_%d", "XSAL_Shm", key, subkey);
```

Making a point of always using `snprintf` is an easy way to avoid the possibility of buffer overflow with `sprintf`.

(It's true that `sprintf` *can* be used safely in some circumstances, and in fact this is one of them, because in this case the size of the expansions of `%s`, `%d`, and `%d` can be easily predicted, and therefore you can have a nice, truly safe size for `shm_name`.  But since many uses of `sprintf` are potentially unsafe -- including those where `%s` is used with more arbitrary strings -- getting into the habit of always using `snprintf` is safer.)

---

Addendum: I missed the fact that the question is asking about decompiled code.  I agree with several other commentators that it's quite likely the string `"/XSAL_Shm_"` might well have resulted from macro expansion -- in other words, the actual original code might have been something like

```
#define XSAL_SHM_PREFIX "/XSAL_Shm_"

sprintf(shm_name, "%s%d_%d", XSAL_SHM_PREFIX, key, subkey);
```

which doesn't look nearly so weird.

Comment: One objective reason to do this might be if `"XSAL_Shm"` was the result of a macro expansion and it wasn't clearly documented/enforced that the macro had to behave as a literal in a format-string context (i.e. not contain `%`).